# jQuery Javascript HTML 5 Export Buttons do not appear and remove other buttons

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, datatables

I am currently trying to add some export buttons to my datatables table.

I have all the correct JS and CSS files loaded e.g.

```
<!--Table JS & CSS-->
    <script src="../plugins/DataTables/DataTables-1.10.12/js/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
    <script src="../plugins/DataTables/DataTables-1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../plugins/DataTables/DataTables-1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>

<!--Button JS & CSS-->
    <script src="../plugins/DataTables/DataTables-1.10.12/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../plugins/DataTables/DataTables-1.10.12/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../plugins/DataTables/DataTables-1.10.12/js/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../plugins/DataTables/DataTables-1.10.12/js/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="../plugins/DataTables/DataTables-1.10.12/js/buttons.html5.min"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../plugins/DataTables/DataTables-1.10.12/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"/>
```

When I load the JS it removes my "Entries" function and "Fuzzy Search" function.

It also does not display the HTML5 buttons?!

The JavaScript is as below

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#example thead th').each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).append( '<input type="text" class="filter_box" placeholder="Filter" />' );
    } );

    // DataTable
    var table = $('#example').DataTable(
    {   
        //Set display length
        "iDisplayLength": 100

    }
    );

    // Apply the search
    table.columns().every( function () {
        var that = this;

                $( 'input', this.header() ).on( 'click', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        } );

        $( 'input', this.header() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {

            if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                that
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
        } );
    } );
} );
</script>
```

If I remove the below JavaScript then the page loads OK e.g. with "Entries" function and "Fuzzy Search" function but obviously no HTML5 Buttons

```
//Set Button settings
dom: 'lBfrtip',
buttons: [
    'copyHtml5',
    'excelHtml5',
    'csvHtml5',
    'pdfHtml5'
]
```

Data is from HTML table e.g.

```
<table width="100%" class="compact stripe hover row-border order-column" id="example">
    <thead class="results_thead">
        <tr>
            <th>W/h<br></th>
            <th>Product<br></th>
            <th>Description<br></th>
            <th>Free Stock<br></th>
            <th>On Order Qty<br></th>
            <th>Make or Buy<br></th>
            <th>Last Trans Date<br></th>
            <th>Last Trans Type<br></th>
            <th>Analysis B<br></th>
            <th>Next Order No<br></th>
            <th>Next On Order Qty<br></th>
            <th>Next Date Req<br></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="results_tbody">
        <tr style="text-align: center">
            <td>'.$row['warehouse'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['product'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['description'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['negative_free_stock'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['on_order_qty'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['make_or_buy'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['last_transaction_date'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['last_transaction_type'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['analysis_b'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['next_order_no'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['next_on_order_qty'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['next_date_required'].'</td>
        </tr>';
</tbody>
</table>
```

So I assume the issue lies with the code above??

Any ideas are much appreciated

Bepster

Comment: create  demo that reproduces problem. should be able to get all the resources needed from a cdn

Comment: Hi Cherlietfl,

Thanks for your advice I rebuilt my page using the CDN paths instead and re tried and it worked fine so went one by one through the JS and CSS files and redownloaded them and checked one at a time and issue has now been resolved! Feel free to add a reply along the lines of check with CDN sources and ill mark as correct answer as may help someone else who is viewing this

Answer (score 0):

```
   I have solve the problem by changing html table structure
    you can see the Demo
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dipakthoke07/ebRXw/2229/

Comment: @bepster please go through Demo it will help you to understand  fault ! and also see Js & CSS file  which  i have included.  where do you want searching functionality at top or at the bottom of the datatable? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Hi Dipak,

I need the search code to remain as it puts the filter box at the top of the page and it also stops the filter box from sorting when you click inside the button.

I am still left with an issue, my code is working fine but as soon as I add the single line:

"dom: 'lBfrtip'," It removes my entries options and fuzzy search options.

Comment: @bepster i solve your issue please click on this link this http://jsfiddle.net/dipakthoke07/ebRXw/2215/  visit link

Comment: Hi Dipak, thanks for the quiick reply! I dont think you understand I need to keep the "// Apply the search" section the same as if you look at your jsfiddle code when you click in the filter boxes below each heading it sorts on that column. This is not the desired effect I want. I need to be able to click in the filter boxes and filter, and when you want to sort click the headings (This works in my code)

I am also using a HTML datasource as well if this makes any difference I have edited my post to include how it currently is written.

Comment: i got your problem

Comment: Hi @bepster i have modify the solution please look into this you need to change table structure .Hope this will your expected answer Thank You !